# LaTeX Table not Compiling

Tags: tables, compiling

I am trying to compile the following table in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
\toprule
Temperature ($^{\circ}$F) & Average melting time (s) & 95\% CI \\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
  130 & 38.75 & (28.54, 48.96) \\
  140 & 21.31 & (9.94, 32.69) \\
  150 & 15.36 & (3.61, 27.11) \\ [0.5ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{The means and 95\% confidence intervals for each temperature.}
\label{tbl:q1a}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I try and compile, it says that the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` commands are not defined, but I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you learn about `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` to use them in your `table`? They come from [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), so `\usepackage{booktabs}` in your preamble and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` stems from [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). If you wish to use it, add `\usepackage{booktabs}` to the preamble.

Note that `booktabs`' horizontal rules leads to poorly-formed vertical rules if you use them. As such, the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) proclaims

> You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times:
>
> 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
> 2. Never use double rules

Below is a rework of your table that doesn't use any vertical rules. A minor addition of [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) allows for alignment of the confidence interval column around the `,`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
    \toprule
    Temperature ($^{\circ}$F) & Average melting time (s) & 95\% CI \\
    \midrule
    130 & 38.75 & \eqmakebox[CI][r]{(28.54, 48.96)} \\
    140 & 21.31 & \eqmakebox[CI][r]{(9.94, 32.69)}  \\
    150 & 15.36 & \eqmakebox[CI][r]{(3.61, 27.11)}  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The means and 95\% confidence intervals for each temperature.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```